# How to run streamlit through docker?

Tags: windows, docker, streamlit

I want to run the streamlit through docker. I did not find any official image. Can someone please guide me with the steps required to achieve this or Dockerimage for streamlit?

Here is the details

```
Operating System: Windows 10 Home 

Docker version 19.03.1

Streamlit, version 0.61.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can look into this [docker hub image](https://hub.docker.com/r/marcskovmadsen/awesome-streamlit).

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 --entrypoint "streamlit" marcskovmadsen/awesome-streamlit:latest run app.py
```

Not sure about the streamlit version but you can create one base on this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/MarcSkovMadsen/awesome-streamlit/blob/master/devops/docker/Dockerfile.base).

Or you can explore [streamlit-docker](https://github.com/domoritz/streamlit-docker), working for me on my local system.

Answer (score 1):

## Quick Setup (own image)

### `Dockerfile`

```
# Nicked from: https://github.com/markdouthwaite/streamlit-project/blob/master/Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8.4-slim

RUN pip install -U pip

COPY requirements.txt app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r app/requirements.txt

# copy into a directory of its own (so it isn't in the toplevel dir)
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["python", "-m", "streamlit.cli", "run", "main.py", "--server.port=8080"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

### `requirements.txt`

Then, in the same directory, example contents of the `requirements.txt` file:

```
streamlit==0.76.0
pandas==1.2.1
numpy==1.19.5
```

### `docker-compose.yml`

In a directory above your Dockerfile and source code, you can add:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
    streamlit:
        build:
          context: streamlit/
        volumes:
          - ./streamlit:/app
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
```